# Force Vertical Scrollbar to be Visible in Panel

Tags: vb.net

I have a Windows Forms VB.NET application, with a panel that contains a few other controls.

I set the panel's AutoScroll property to True, and that seems to appropriately apply the scroll bars when they are needed.  The issue is that a user must scroll all the way to the right to access the vertical scroll bar.  Is there a way to always show the vertical scrollbar no matter where the user is scrolled horizontally?

**EDIT**
I guess the main problem I have here is that I have a DataGridView inside of a panel.  I want the panel to do the vertical scrolling, and not the DataGridView.  Why is it when I turn off vertical scrollbars on the datagridview and have autoscroll on the panel, a vertical scroll bar is never shown?

Comment: You did something wrong.  Did you put a panel inside another panel?

Comment: I have multiple panels inside panels.  It's so I can create my own custom panels and use them throughout the application.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `VScrollBar` on the right side of the panel and set code behind to move the panel scroll up and down.

or

A better option may be to switch your panel to a `FlowLayoutPanel` which provides quite a bit of control over the scroll handles both vertical and horizontal.

Check out [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel_properties.aspx) and see how to use all of the properties of the FLP: